# Why is diff returning an incorrect value?

Tags: php, datetime, diff

Diff is returning an incorrect value, incorrect meaning it isn't what is expected. I need it to return total minutes, for example 1 hour and 7 minutes needs to be 67 minutes.

```
<?php
// Trouble-shoot why time is being calculate incorrectly at 7 minutes when
// it should be 67 minutes for total travel time.

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
// Display the total travel time in minutes for a trip.

    $depart = "10:31:00 07/30/2013";
    $arrival = "7/30/2013 11:38:00 AM";

    echo "depart time is: " . $depart . "\n";
    echo "arrival time is: " . $arrival . "\n";
    $depart_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $depart);
    $arrival_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $arrival);
    var_dump($depart_raw);
    var_dump($arrival_raw);
    $interval = $depart_raw->diff($arrival_raw);
    var_dump($interval);
    echo "Total travel time is: " . $interval->format("%i")." minutes" . "\n";

?>
```

Output:

```
depart time is: 10:31:00 07/30/2013
arrival time is: 7/30/2013 11:38:00 AM
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-07-30 10:31:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-07-30 11:38:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(1)
  ["i"]=>
  int(7)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
}
Total travel time is: 7 minutes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be getting a correct interval, however, you are only showing the 'minutes' part of it, and not the hours. `var_dump($interval)` to see what I mean - the total interval is 1 hour and 7 minutes.

Your mistake is assuming the `%i` format will give you 67 minutes - it will not. You could calculate it with something like this:

```
$minutes= 
   $interval->format("%a")*24*60 + //total days
   $interval->format("%H")*60 +    //hours
   $interval->format("%i");        //minutes
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: So how do I display total minutes then such as 67 minutes? Thanks!

Comment: I get the %H and the %i, but what does your %a do in this calculation? Thanks.

Comment: integer addition is tricky at first, but if you persevere it will soon "click" and you will fear it no longer.

Comment: I think it might be time for you RTFM http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: I see you were being more complete to include days past. These are short train trips, however they might cross over to another day. Thanks again for your help today, Paul. I was expecting all this "fancy" OO stuff to have the entire value I needed squirrel away somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This would output the result you expected

```
$traveltime = 60 * $interval->format("%H") + $interval->format("%i");
echo "Total travel time is: " . $traveltime . " minutes" . "\n";`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Total travel time is: " .$interval->format("%h") ." hours and " . $interval->format("%i")." minutes" . "\n";
```

You're only showing the minutes and not the hours. It converts the minutes into hours and stores them in a different part of the array.

```
  ["h"]=>
  int(1)

  ["i"]=>
  int(7)
```

In that case, just do:

```
 echo "Total travel time is: " . ($interval->format("%i")+($interval->format("%h")*60))." minutes" . "\n";
```

Comment: I updated it (please see above). I need total minutes, so 1 hour and 7 minutes needs to be 67 minutes, for example.